# Update specific value in a field MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table wp_blogs as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_blogs` (
  `blog_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `domain` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `path` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `registered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `last_updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `public` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `archived` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mature` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `spam` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lang_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`blog_id`),
  KEY `domain` (`domain`(50),`path`(5)),
  KEY `lang_id` (`lang_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `wp_blogs` (`blog_id`, `site_id`, `domain`, `path`, `registered`, `last_updated`, `public`, `archived`, `mature`, `spam`, `deleted`, `lang_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'wordpress1001.com', '/rooturl/', '2015-02-18 02:45:37', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(2, 1, 'wordpress1001.com', '/rooturl/site1/', '2015-02-18 02:49:08', '2015-02-18 02:49:27', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(3, 1, 'wordpress1001.com', '/rooturl/site2/', '2015-02-18 02:50:09', '2015-02-18 02:50:38', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(4, 1, 'wordpress1001.com', '/rooturl/site3/', '2015-02-18 02:50:59', '2015-02-18 02:51:35', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I want to update field path to some other name.
For ex:-

```
(1, 1, 'wordpress1001.com', '/testurl/', '2015-02-18 02:45:37', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(2, 1, 'wordpress1001.com', '/testurl/site1/', '2015-02-18 02:49:08', '2015-02-18 02:49:27', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(3, 1, 'wordpress1001.com', '/testurl/site2/', '2015-02-18 02:50:09', '2015-02-18 02:50:38', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(4, 1, 'wordpress1001.com', '/testurl/site3/', '2015-02-18 02:50:59', '2015-02-18 02:51:35', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

rooturl or testurl will be the dynamic value. I will change depend upon customer.But the site1,site2 and site3 is constant. 
Can any one help me to write a sql query to update table?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by dynamic? Is it determined according to other values in the table?

Comment: You want to change 'testurl' but keep /site1, /site2 etc correct?

Comment: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ This tool might help to quickly change url values in a whole Wordpress DB.